# Record Triggered Flow Order of Operations

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, workflow

I have a Salesforce long text area field called "Status Comments" on the case object. When a user saves text into this field, I have two separate record triggered flows that need to process.

- Flow 1: This flow takes the Status Comment and stamps it onto another object
- Flow 2: This flow takes the status Comment and sets it back to NULL

Right now I set up the order so that Flow 1 runs before Flow 2.

What I am finding is that Flow 1 is constantly showing the "Status Comment" field as blank. This should not be the case, because Flow 2, which resets the field back to blank runs AFTER flow 1.

It might be due to how Salesforce handles field updates in the transaction lifecycle.

In Salesforce flow, all the field updates within a transaction are not actually committed until after all the transaction's operations are completed. This means that even though Flow 1 is intended to run first, it might not be seeing the new "Status Comment" because the update to that field has not been committed to the database at the time Flow 1 runs.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Would you mind including screenshots of the flows and flow builder setup so we can see what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I updated my flows API from Version 50 to 57 and it is now working

Comment: Thanks I was going crazy trying to figure out why Flow Order it was not working - updating all the flows with ordering to the latest API fixed it